# MySQL database and importing dates problems

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Okay,so in my mysql database I use a date field. Using PHP I check if the user is 18 years of age or not. Then I try to enter all the form information to my MySQL database to make a user.  I keep getting a blank screen (besides my navbar and footer)  The user is not being saved into the database, and the error log shows this error: PHP  Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in ....

```
$age = checkAge($_POST["birthday"]);
if($age != false) 
{
  $ageSuc = "All Good!";
}
else ....


function checkAge ($data)
{
  $dateObj = new DateTime($data);
  $ageLimit = new DateTime('-18 years');
  if ($dateObj > $ageLimit)
  {
   return false;
  }
  else 
  {
    $dateObj->format('Y-m-d');
    return $dateObj;
  }
}
```

So the question is, do I need to convert the dateTime Obj into a string before MySQL will accept it? The field is set to hold 'dates'  so I thought the date obj would be the same thing? How does one change it to a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning the DateTime object, because the `format` function returns a string, it doesn't change the object. Try returning the result of the format function which is the [formatted string](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

```
return $dateObj->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: won't that return it as an obj still? or would that convert it to a string? To me it looks like what I did, except you did it with one line..

Comment: @user3448741 that will return the string date in that format

Comment: I'll give it a shot!

Comment: @user3448741 ok great, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

```
$age = checkAge($_POST["birthday"]);
  if($age != false)
     {
       $ageSuc = "All Good!";
     }
  else ....


 function checkAge ($data)
    {
       $dateObj = new DateTime($data);
       $ageLimit = new DateTime('-18 years');
       if ($dateObj > $ageLimit)
         {
           return false;
          }
          else 
           {
             return $dateObj->format('Y-m-d');
            }
      }
```

If you want a string result, you have to return the `format()` result, not the object itself.

But the error you have specified is not triggered directly in this code, but somewhere in the `else`, where you try to convert the result to string.

Comment: A bit late on replying to this, but Incase anyone is having this problem here is my feedback to your answer...  I found out your right by saying I have to return the format() result, however the error WAS a result from that code piece,, as I was returning the object itself, not the string result from format().